# MOngodb mongoexport query issue

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoexport

I am unable to export data with below condition, can someone help me resolve this?

--below is the query which I am using in mongoexport.

```
'{ ts: {$gt: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 15)}}'
```

--below is the error:

```
2017-03-09T14:53:23.595-0800    error validating settings: query '[123 32 116 115 58 32 123 36 103 116 58 32 110 101 119 32 68 97 116 101 40 73 83 79 68 97 116 101 40 41 46 103 101 116 84 105 109 101 40 41 32 45 32 49 48 48 48 32 42 32 54 48 32 42 32 49 53 41 125 125]' is not valid JSON: invalid character '.' after constructor argument
2017-03-09T14:53:23.595-0800    try 'mongoexport --help' for more information
```

Comment: `ISODate().getTime()` is not a valid  operation for mongo export. Pass the calculated long millis to the `new Date` function directly.